# How to display content submission page to users?

Tags: drupal, admin

I would like to add a page where users can submit content (not just a comment, but a specific 'content type' including the relevant fields). I could use the regular admin link but that would require alternating the admin theme a lot and also would need to hide/disable things i otherwise need.

Is there a good way to display a submission form to the users through which they can submit content? I was looking for a solution via 'Views' but didn't get far.

I hope i managed to get my point across.

Answer (score 2):

drupal 6 or drupal 7?

in drupal 7 you have the field API that is very helpfull to get the fields of an entity.

in drupal 6 you can create your own form with forms API and run node_save() in the submit function.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem with using the usual node/add/node-type page is that you don't want users to see the admin theme, then you don't have a problem. You can disable the admin theme for non-admin users - on the permissions page, look for "System / View the administration theme". It's already unchecked by default, I think. Any adminny-type pages they access will use your default public-facing theme.